# CNN Architecture with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am implementing the architecture found within this paper https://cs.nyu.edu/~fergus/papers/zeilerECCV2014.pdf using TensorFlow.

[image: CNN]

I have formatted my input to be `224, 224, 3` and have the following TensorFlow layers. The issue I am getting is that the output size of `conv1` is not 110 by 110 by 96 as the paper states, rather 109 by 109 by 96. How can I fix this?

I have followed the hyperparemeters specified in the paper on page 8. My only idea is that the padding may be incorrect (as TensorFlow sets it for you).

My code is as below:

```
# Input Layer
# Reshape X to 4-D tensor: [batch_size, width, height, channels]
input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3])

print(input_layer.get_shape(), '224, 224, 3')
# Convolutional Layer #1
# Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 224, 224, 3]
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=input_layer,
    filters=96,
    kernel_size=[7, 7],
    strides=2,
    padding="valid",  # padding = 1
    activation=tf.nn.relu)
print(conv1.get_shape(), '110, 110, 96')

# Max Pooling Layer
# Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 110, 110, 96]
pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[3, 3], strides=2)

# Contrast Normalisation
# Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 55, 55, 96]
contrast_norm1 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(
    pool1,
    depth_radius=5,
    bias=1,
    alpha=0.0001,
    beta=0.75)
print(contrast_norm1.get_shape(), '55, 55, 96')

# The rest of the CNN...
```

Output: In-brackets - actual dimensions, outside - desired/paper dimensions

```
(?, 224, 224, 3) 224, 224, 3  # Input
(?, 109, 109, 96) 110, 110, 96  # Following conv1
(?, 54, 54, 96) 55, 55, 96  # Following contrast_norm1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output height and width dimensions of convolution operation with `valid` padding can be calculated as:

```
output_size = (input_size - kernel_size) // stride + 1
```

In your case, the outupt of first layer:

```
output_size = (224 - 7) // 2 + 1 = 217 // 2 + 1 = 109
```

One way to make the output of first layer to be equal to 110 is to set the kernel size to `6x6`. The other way could be adding padding of size 1 using [tf.pad](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad):

```
# suppose this is a batch of 10 images of size 4x4x3
data = np.ones((10, 4, 4, 3), dtype=np.float32)

paddings = [[0, 0], # no values are added along batch dim
            [1, 0], # add one value before the content of height dim
            [1, 0], # add one value before the content of width dim
            [0, 0]] # no values are added along channel dim

padded_data = tf.pad(tensor=data,
                     paddings=paddings,
                     mode='CONSTANT',
                     constant_values=0)

sess = tf. InteractiveSession()
output = sess.run(padded_data)
print(output.shape)
# >>> (10, 5, 5, 3)

# print content of first channel of first image
print(output[0,:,:,0])
# >>> [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#      [0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
#      [0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
#      [0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
#      [0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

In the example above, zero-padding of size 1 is added along height and width dimensions. The padding should be of shape `[number_of_dimensions, 2]`, e.g. for each dimension of the input matrix you specify how many values to add before and after the content of the tensor.

If you apply this padding to your input data it will result in a tensor of shape `batch x 225 x 225 x 3`, thus the output height and width of the convolutional layer will be `110x110`.

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind explaining the `[[1,0],[1,0]]` I'm finding the documentation confusing.

Comment: I get the following: `ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 4 for 'Pad' (op: 'Pad') with input shapes: [?,224,224,3], [2,2].`

Comment: @Wizard the example I provided was for 2d tensors. I have now updated the code to include an example for 4d tensor. I would suggest to run that example with different paddings, e.g `[[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,0]]` or `[[0,0],[2,0],[1,3],[0,0]]` to see what these values mean and how they affect the output.